# PHP Uppercase first three words of a string

Tags: php

How do I uppercase the first three words of a string?

I've tried using the below, but it doesn't work.

```
<p><?php echo strtoupper(substr($copy, 0, 3)) . substr($copy, 3); ?></p>
```

Thanks

Comment: First three words or first three letters?

Comment: Your code only does the [first three letters](http://codepad.viper-7.com/lC7a5N)

Comment: And your sample code does not duplicate the string. That's different code, that you haven't shown.

Comment: The first three words.

Comment: I was mistaken; my code just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This iterates over the first three words found in the string and applies uppercase:

```
$copy = 'hello world bla hohoho';

echo preg_replace_callback('/\w+/', function($m) {
  return strtoupper($m[0]);
}, $copy, 3);
```

Comment: Accepted as this was the only that I could understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$words = preg_split('/\s/', $copy);
if(is_array($words)) {
   $counter = 0;
   foreach($words as $word) {
     if($counter < 3) {
       echo ucfirst(strtolower($word)), " ";
     } else {
       echo $word, " ";
     }
     $counter++;
   }
}
```

[Example](https://eval.in/171977)

Comment: That's a great answer for copy and pasting. (More effort than neccessary though). Newcomers are best helped with a little explanation however.

Comment: Probably fails on `'   word'`.

Comment: @mario Are you asserting I copied / pasted this answer? I wrote this my own 2 hands for this site just now.

Comment: He meant that this answer is great to *be* copied and pasted, not that you did so.

Comment: This just uppercases the first letter of every word. Does this loop through the string?

Comment: @mario, what is your "(More effort than neccessary though). "?

Comment: ok just had to change strtolower to strtoupper; works now. Would be nice to explain what this does. Thank you.

Comment: Why did you have swap strtoupper, strtolower @user1381806

Comment: Well, split and iterate is kinda long-winded. If you just matched the first three words (e.g. `/(\w+\b\W*){3}/`) a preg_replace_callback for strtoupper would suffice.